# rxjs BehaviorSubject.next not been trigger

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I am working with angular 5 and i have a problem. I am using a BehaviorSubject in a service. On A component i am consuming that service. but the subscriber never get called. While debugging i realize that the BehaviorSubject has no observers attached to it. I am trying to intercept the http request to display a spinner.

**SERVICE**

```
import { HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest, HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class HttpInterceptorProgress implements HttpInterceptor {

    private loadingCount = 0;
    public isHttpLoadingSubject = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

    public intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>>  {

        console.log('before');
        this.loadingIncrement();

        return next.handle(req).do(
            (event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
                if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
                    console.log('ok');
                    this.loadingDecrement();
                }
            },
            (err: any) => {
                console.log('error');
                this.loadingDecrement();
            });
    }

    private loadingIncrement()
    {
        this.loadingCount = this.loadingCount + 1;
        this.isHttpLoadingSubject.next(true);
    }

    private loadingDecrement()
    {
        this.loadingCount = this.loadingCount - 1;

        if (this.loadingCount === 0)
        {
            this.isHttpLoadingSubject.next(false);
        }
    }
}
```

**COMPONENT**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpInterceptorProgress } from './HttpInterceptorProgress';
import { IObservableAlive } from './IObservableAlive';

@Component({
    selector: 'loader',
    templateUrl: 'loaderComponent.html'
})
export class LoaderComponent implements IObservableAlive {

    public isAlive: boolean;
    private httpInPregress: Boolean;

    constructor(private interceptor: HttpInterceptorProgress) { }

    public ngOnDestroy(): void {
        this.isAlive = false;
    }

    public ngOnInit(): void {
        this.httpInPregress = false;
        this.isAlive = true;

        this.interceptor.isHttpLoadingSubject
            .takeWhile(() => this.isAlive)
            .subscribe((isLoading: Boolean) => {
                this.httpInPregress = isLoading;
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: where you provided `HttpInterceptorProgress` ?

Comment: is that worked ???

Comment: I'm not completely sure but try adding `implements OnInit` when defining the component.

Comment: @martin Implementing the interface is optional. Though recommended, it has no functional impact.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it was my fault, I was doing this on my app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({ ...
    providers: [HttpInterceptorProgress,  {
        provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, 
        useClass: HttpInterceptorProgress, 
        multi: true 
    })
```

That was creating 2 instances of the HttpInterceptorProgress service. One of then was been injected into the component, the other was actually handling the http request interceptions.

I need now to find out a way to communicate between the HttpInterceptorProgress 
 interceptor and the LoaderComponent component

Thanks very much all for your comments.